# Angular 11 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in console on application load

Tags: angular

I have an angular 11 application which is showing the following error when the application loads:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at new UnsubscriptionErrorImpl (vendor.js:108526)
    at SafeSubscriber.unsubscribe (vendor.js:109081)
    at SafeSubscriber.unsubscribe (vendor.js:20561)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (vendor.js:20726)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (vendor.js:20650)
    at Subscriber._next (vendor.js:20566)
    at Subscriber.next (vendor.js:20531)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (vendor.js:60648)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (vendor.js:2843)
defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:70746
```

Is this some angular config issue or something specific that I need to look into?

How can I fix this?

Comment: it's code related : as BehaviorSubject is mentionned, i would suggest you to look at your code. Such error might occur by pushing a new value to the BehaviorSubject when subscribing to it (making it never ending).

Comment: Is there a way to know what component or service the error is coming from?

Comment: no with a such error message